# Problem with parsing an image into a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to pass some images to a numpy array for training a deep neural network. I am using cv2 and the code goes like this

```
def dataloader(filepath, subset):
    # Initiliaze return arrays - input of shape = HYPERPARAMETER
    global size
    if subset=="train":
        size = 129
    elif subset=="test":
        size = 18
    input_data=np.zeros((size,1024,1024,1))
    output_data=np.zeros((size,1024,1024,1))
    # Open file and create loop
    with open(filepath+"annotation_"+subset+".txt", "r") as input_file:
        # Count to pass through the file
        count=0
        for line in input_file:
            line.split()
            input_data[count,:,:,0]=cv2.imread(filepath+str(line[0])+".jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

but this way my input is all nan and i cannot get why. Shouldnt the image be passed on as the 2d format I need. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: start with chekcing what `cv2.imread(filepath+str(line[0])+".jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)` returns.

Comment: OpenCV doesn’t throw an error when it can’t read the image file, it just returns None. You need to check its output always.